# php while loop not displaying rows after 15 rows

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo, while-loop

Hello I have Two files one file contain the main posts and second file contain load more posts code

Following are the code of main file but in this file i have a problem that i have to loop my all mysql rows in php and i can do it using while loop but when i try this i am getting all rows but after 15 rows it shows only those that are after 15 rows like only 16 row

My main.php code

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $nv_name_split = str_replace('_', ' ', $row['novel_name']);
    echo '<br><a href="episode?novel='.$row['novel_name'].'&episode='.$row['episode_num'].'"><figure class="snip1253"><div class="image"><img width="100%"src="images/sneakpeaks/'.$row['sneak_peak'].'" alt="sample59"/></div><figcaption>'.
            '<div class="date"><span class="day">'.$row['day'].'</span><span class="month">'.$row['month'].'</span></div><h3>Episode # '.$row['episode_num'].'</h3>  <footer>
            <div class="writer text-center"><i class="fa fa-book"> '.$nv_name_split.'</i></div>
            <div class="love"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>'.$row['likes'].'</div>
            <div class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>'.$row['comments'].'</div></footer></figure></a></figcaption><br><br>';
}
?>
<?php 
$stmt_count = $novel_list->runQuery("SELECT episode_num 
                                    FROM posts 
                                    WHERE just_skpk='0'");
$stmt_count->execute();
while ($rows = $stmt_count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $count_row = $rows['episode_num'];
}
if ($limit < $count_row) {
    echo'<form id="frm_more_post">
            <center>
            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-load_more" id="frm_btn_more">Load More Posts</button>
            </center>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>';
}else{
    echo'<form id="frm_more_post">
            <center>
            <button type="submit" disabled class="disabled form-control btn btn-load_more" id="frm_btn_more">No More Posts</button>
            </center>
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>'; 
}
```

and this is my load_more.php code where i post limit of posts using ajax

load_more.php code

```
$novel_list = new USER();

if (isset($_POST['page'])) {   
    $limit = $_POST['page']+3;
    $stmt = $novel_list->runQuery("SELECT * 
                                    FROM posts 
                                    WHERE just_skpk='0' 
                                    ORDER BY id DESC 
                                    LIMIT $limit");
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount(0)) {
        echo '<input class="hidden" id="pages" value="'.$limit.'"/>';

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $nv_name_split = str_replace('_', ' ', $row['novel_name']);
            echo '<br><a data-pages="'.$limit.'" href="episode?novel='.$row['novel_name'].'&episode='.$row['episode_num'].'"><figure class="snip1253"><div class="image"><img width="100%"src="images/sneakpeaks/'.$row['sneak_peak'].'" alt="sample59"/></div><figcaption>'.

                '<div class="date"><span class="day">'.$row['day'].'</span><span class="month">'.$row['month'].'</span></div><h3>Episode # '.$row['episode_num'].'</h3>  <footer>

                <div class="writer text-center"><i class="fa fa-book"> '.$nv_name_split.'</i></div>

                <div class="love"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>'.$row['likes'].'</div>

                <div class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>'.$row['comments'].'</div></footer></figure></a></figcaption><br><br>';

        }

        $stmt_count = $novel_list->runQuery("SELECT episode_num 
                                            FROM posts 
                                            WHERE just_skpk='0'");

        $stmt_count->execute();

        while ($rows == $stmt_count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $count_row = $rows['episode_num'];
        }
        if ($limit < $count_row) {
            echo '<form id="frm_more_post">
                    <center>
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-load_more" id="frm_btn_more">Load More Posts</button>
                     </center>
                  </form>
                  <br>
                  <br>';
        }else{
            echo '<form id="frm_more_post">
                    <center>
                        <button type="submit" disabled class="disabled form-control btn btn-load_more" id="frm_btn_more">No More Posts</button>
                    </center>
                   </form>
                   <br>
                   <br>'; 
        }
    }else{
        echo 0 ;
    }
}
```

i solve first problem in main.php while loop using double == in while loop but in load_more.php file i cant show more posts button it shows disabled but when i have less than 15 rows in database its working perfectly please help me to show load more posts button in load_more.php.

ThankYou,
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the point, other than making the code difficult to read, in stopping the PHP compiler `?>` and on the very next line starting it again `<?php` ????

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: "after 15 rows it shows only those that are after 15 rows" Well, wouldn't that make sense?  You're not wanting to repeat the first 15 over and over, are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are getting episode_num as $count_row, but it should be no of rows. Try below code

```
$novel_list = new USER();

if (isset($_POST['page'])) {   
    $limit = $_POST['page']+3;
    $stmt = $novel_list->runQuery("SELECT * 
                                    FROM posts 
                                    WHERE just_skpk='0' 
                                    ORDER BY id DESC 
                                    LIMIT $limit");
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount(0)) {
        echo '<input class="hidden" id="pages" value="'.$limit.'"/>';

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $nv_name_split = str_replace('_', ' ', $row['novel_name']);
            echo '<br><a data-pages="'.$limit.'" href="episode?novel='.$row['novel_name'].'&episode='.$row['episode_num'].'"><figure class="snip1253"><div class="image"><img width="100%"src="images/sneakpeaks/'.$row['sneak_peak'].'" alt="sample59"/></div><figcaption>'.

                '<div class="date"><span class="day">'.$row['day'].'</span><span class="month">'.$row['month'].'</span></div><h3>Episode # '.$row['episode_num'].'</h3>  <footer>

                <div class="writer text-center"><i class="fa fa-book"> '.$nv_name_split.'</i></div>

                <div class="love"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>'.$row['likes'].'</div>

                <div class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>'.$row['comments'].'</div></footer></figure></a></figcaption><br><br>';

        }

        $stmt_count = $novel_list->runQuery("SELECT count(*) as cnt 
                                            FROM posts 
                                            WHERE just_skpk='0'");

        $stmt_count->execute();

        while ($rows = $stmt_count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $count_row = $rows['cnt'];
        }
        if ($limit < $count_row) {
            echo '<form id="frm_more_post">
                    <center>
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-load_more" id="frm_btn_more">Load More Posts</button>
                     </center>
                  </form>
                  <br>
                  <br>';
        }else{
            echo '<form id="frm_more_post">
                    <center>
                        <button type="submit" disabled class="disabled form-control btn btn-load_more" id="frm_btn_more">No More Posts</button>
                    </center>
                   </form>
                   <br>
                   <br>'; 
        }
    }else{
        echo 0 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just removed double == from while in load_more.php and it's working thank you for count rows

Comment: I’ll update the answer to reflect that. I didn’t see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this because of the pagination. In the file load_more.php, you are setting a limit

```
$limit = $_POST['page']+3;
```

and in the file, main.php

```
if ($limit < $count_row)
```

this is the check.